# Laravel: cannot access item from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I've got some data returned as a collection from a relationship:

```
$item = $this->detailedItems->where('detaileditem_product_id', $productId);
```

when printing this out I can see the data I'm looking for but when trying to access it:

```
$item->detaileditem_id;
```

or

```
$item->detaileditem_name;
```

I'm getting an error:

> Exception: Property [detaileditem_id] does not exist on this
>   collection instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where) returns a filtered collection, not a single item.

If you want the first item of that collection that matches your condition, use first:

```
$item = $this->detailedItems->where('detaileditem_product_id', $productId)->first();
```